# When I change route the whole app refreshes and doesnt seem like a single page app

Tags: routes, typescript, angular

**When I change route the whole app refreshes and doesnt seem like a single page app**

My typescript compiles fine and the app all works.
But when I change route e.g. to /register page the browser reloads the whole page.

Is it because of my nav bar?
The nav bar is in the app.ts, should I move it to make the app smoother for link change?

**Here is my app.ts file:**

```
  import {Component, View, bootstrap, bind, provide} from 'angular2/angular2';
  import {Router, ROUTER_BINDINGS, RouterOutlet, RouteConfig, RouterLink, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, APP_BASE_HREF} from 'angular2/router';
  import {Injectable} from 'angular2/angular2';
  import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, Headers} from 'angular2/http';

  import {AuthService} from './authService';
  import {Login} from './components/login/login';
  import {Register} from './components/register/register';

  @Component({
      selector: 'app'
  })

  @View({
      template: `
      <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Pool Cover</a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="/login">Log In <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="/register">Sign up</a></li>                    
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>      
    </header>

    <div class="content">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet> 
    </div>
  `,
      directives: [RouterOutlet, RouterLink]
  })

  @RouteConfig([
      { path: '/', redirectTo: '/login' },
      { path: '/login', component: Login, as: 'Login' },
      { path: '/register', component: Register, as: 'Register' },
  ])

  @Injectable()

  export class AppComponent {}

  bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue: '/'}), HTTP_PROVIDERS, AuthService]);
```

**Here is my index.html:**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <base href="/"></base>
      <title>Title</title>

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/src/bootstraptheme.css" />

      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.18.4/system.src.js"></script>    

      <script>
          System.config({
              transpiler: 'typescript',
              defaultJSExtensions: true
          });
      </script>

      <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
      <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
      <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.js"></script>
      <script src="/src/firebase/firebaseNew.js"></script>  

    </head>

    <body id="container">

      <app></app>

      <script>      
        System.import('src/app/app');
      </script>

    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I have that - see above code

Comment: You need to read the documentation : [RouterLink](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/RouterLink-directive.html)

Comment: are you sure that the page really reloads? does the browser do again all the requests for the js, css and html files?

Comment: I'm basically trying to get the nav bar to stay and only reload content where route outlet is on route change eg when I click a link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [RouterLink](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/RouterLink-directive.html) page that @EricMartinez mentioned in a comment, you need to use links with the following format:

```
<a [router-link]="['./register']">Sign up</a>
```

See also [Brian's AngularConnect 2015 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z1NB-HG0ZH4) on routing.

Comment: I had to use routerLink instead of router-link. Possibly this changed at some point because I have seen the hyphenated form in a number of places. Latest [docs](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink)  seem to indicate that the camel case version is the correct form.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the page in the browser, the browser will think it needs to reload, click a link and it will work. Remember to put `<base href="/">`

Comment: I did that and it still refreshes the header nav bar when I click a link